# Remove control from repeater before rendering

Tags: asp.net

i want to remove hidden field control from repeater control before rendering i trying to export repeater control to excel

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Repeater newrpt = (Repeater)Cache["Report"];

//remove hidden field from newrpt 
newrpt.RenderControl(htw);
```

this is my code. I need to remove because I am getting error `Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptSafetyIndicator_ctl01_hidSIId' of type 'HiddenField' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any control from ItemTemplate after databinding

```
    repeater.ItemDataBound += delegate(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs ev)
    {
        var hf = ev.Item.FindControl("hidSIId");
        ev.Item.Controls.Remove(hf);
    };
```

But i think the main problem is, that you are calling RenderControl on templated control which must be placed inside FORM control. You can resolve this error by override [Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx)

[Look here for example](http://aspalliance.com/771_CodeSnip_Exporting_GridView_to_Excel)